# How to link Next.js to existing HTML static website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

Currently, I have a static website (HTML and CSS) and I created a blog site using Next.js and Strapi API for my blog. Now I want to link my existing static website with my Next.js project

**I want to add a "blog" link to my static site NavBar which will render the Next.js project is that possible?**

Like this:
mysite.com/  --> is the static site
mysite.com/blog   --> is the Next.js Project

is this possible to implement?

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: This is not possible using purely static things, you'll either need to programmatically check the route in your API and fetch the static content through your first site, or you'll need to configure nginx to proxy on /blog to the other site.  On the other site then you'll have to remove the "blog" from the url request for its routes to still work correctly.